# How can I make a textbox to be the Active.Sheet.range

Tags: textbox, range, declare

I have made a userform with an option to translate some English words to Cyrillic. But when I want to declare the textbox as my range, I get the message "Method 'Range of object'_Global failed. And when I enter the debug button, I see the Set RNG=Range(D3) in yellow, where D3 is the textbox that contains the English words that need to be translated. How can I solve this problem. See my VBA code:

```vba
Private Sub cmdTRANSLATE_Click()
Application.StatusBar = "TRANSLATING THE RECIPE -  TRANSLATING THE RECIPE - TRANSLATING THE RECIPE - TRANSLATING THE RECIPE - TRANSLATING THE RECIPE "
   
   With Application
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .DisplayAlerts = False
   End With
   
   
  Dim Rng As Range
  Dim What As Variant
  Dim Repl  As Variant
  Dim i As Long
    What = Array("(Milk)", "(Celery)", "(Wheat)", "(Sulphites)", "(Crustaceans)", "(Egg)", "(Fish)", "(Soya)", "(Peanuts)", "(Nuts)", "(Mustard)", "(Sesame)", "(Lupin)", "(Molluscs)", "(Egg, Celery)", "(Milk, Egg)")
    Repl = Array("[ÌËßÊÎ]", "[ÖÅËÈÍÀ]", "[ÏØÅÍÈÖÀ]", "[ÑÓËÔÈÒÈ]", "[ÐÀÊÎÎÁÐÀÇÍÈ]", "[ßÉÖÅ]", "[ÐÈÁÀ]", "[ÑÎß]", "[ÔÚÑÒÚÖÈ]", "[ßÄÊÈ]", "[ÃÎÐ×ÈÖÀ]", "[CÓÑÀÌ]", "[ËÓÏÈÍ]", "[ÌÅÊÎÒÅËÈ]", "[ßÉÖÅ, ÖÅËÈÍÀ]", "[ÌËßÊÎ, ËÓÏÈÍ]")
        For i = 0 To UBound(What)
        Set Rng = Range(D3)
        Rng.Replace What:=What(i), replacement:=Repl(i), MatchCase:=False

    Next i

Application.StatusBar = False
End Subs
```

I have tried several different declarations on the range but nothing worked. I am working on this problem for several months now, I just don't remember any more what I have done so far

Comment: i guess all this `your Text`is somehow a mistake...

Comment: yes, it is, should not be there, supposed to be a carriage return